# How to design many-to-many relationships on deletion?

Tags: java, oop, gwt, many-to-many, java-canvas

I'm creating a `canvas` drawing with 2 objects: `Rectangles`, and `Lines` connecting the Rectangles. Each Line should be aware of the 2 `Rectangle`s it connects.
Every `Rectangle` can have multiple lines that connect it to other `Rectangle`s.

```
class Rectangle {
    List<Line> connections;
    void setConnection(Line line) {
        connections.add(line);
    }
}

class Line {
    Rectangle from, to;

    public Line(Rectangle from, Rectangle to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;

        from.setConnection(this);
        to.setConnection(this);
    }
}
```

I feel this might not be a good design, because when I delete a `Line`, I will also have to delete the `Line` from the connections list in the `Rectangle` it connects.

When I delete a `Rectangle`, I also have to remove the `Line`s that are connected to the rectangle, as they should not exist without. Therefore I have to iterate through all `connections` of the deletable `Rectangle`, and for each `connection` get the `from`/`to` `rectangle`, and there again get the `connection` list and remove the `Line` reference.

My problem is not to write that code (I already have it working), but it seems to me I'm doing a lot of back-and-forth references.

Can this be done better? Somehow: if a rectangle is deleted, then all deep connections from the lines are removed/invalidated automatically? Something similar to Hibernate's many-to-many cascading? I can't just use Hibernate because this is supposed to be a client side app, without a database.

Comment: In order for the deep connections to be deleted, they need to be evaluated one way or the other.  You could do that check on deletion, like you have been doing, or you can have it check on access (set pointer to null, then later, when something attempts to access it and sees the null, it deletes the line).  That saves time on the initial deletion, but adds a little overhead for each access and will use more memory if you don't actually access them.  Very similar problem to garbage collection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29)

Comment: You could use a `Map` with a key of type `Rectangle` and a value that is a `Set` of `Line` objects (or a Guava `MultiMap`). This could significantly improve performance if you have a lot of rectangles and lines. You would, of course, remove the `List` of lines from the `Rectangle` class. Actually, I think I'd probably introduce a class that manages the "connection points", and contains the map of rectangles/lines. (btw, I thought that it was better to use a concrete class, such as `ArrayList`, instead of the abstract class `List` when programming with `GWT`?)

Comment: Well, how would a `Map<Rectangle, Set<Line>>` be any different than a `List<Rectangle>` where `Rectangle` holds a `private List<Line> lines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you are building graphs. You will need to separate the edges from the vertices.

Let's start by creating some interfaces that separate some concerns:

```
interface Shape {
}

interface ShapeConnection {
    Shape[] getConnectedShapes();
}
```

Then let's introduce an annotation that will mark shapes that need to cascade delete their connected shapes.

```
@interface CascadeDeleteConnectedShapes {
}
```

Rectangle and Line can then be defined as:

```
@CascadeDeleteConnectedShapes
class Rectangle implements Shape {

}

class Line implements Shape, ShapeConnection {
    Rectangle from, to;

    public Line(Rectangle from, Rectangle to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    @Override
    public Shape[] getConnectedShapes() {
        return new Shape[] { from, to };
    }
}
```

Finally, you will need a place where you can put it all together.

```
class Canvas {
    private ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager();

    private Set<Shape> shapes = new HashSet<Shape>();

    public Canvas() {
    }

    public void removeShape(Shape shape) {
        if (!shapes.remove(shape))
            return; 

        if (shape.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(CascadeDeleteConnectedShapes.class)) {
            cascadeDeleteShape(shape);
        }

        if (shape instanceof ShapeConnection) {
            connectionManager.remove((ShapeConnection) shape);
        }
    }

    private void cascadeDeleteShape(Shape shape) {
        List<ShapeConnection> connections = connectionManager.getConnections(shape);
        for (ShapeConnection connection : connections) {
            if (connection instanceof Shape) {
                this.removeShape((Shape) connection);
            } else {
                connectionManager.remove(connection);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addShape(Shape shape) {
        if (shapes.contains(shape))
            return;

        if (shape instanceof ShapeConnection) {
            addShapeConnection((ShapeConnection) shape);
        }

        shapes.add(shape);
    }

    private void addShapeConnection(ShapeConnection shapeConnection) {
        for (Shape shape : shapeConnection.getConnectedShapes()) {
            if (!shapes.contains(shape))
                throw new Error("cannot connect unknown shapes");
        }
        connectionManager.add(shapeConnection);
    }
}
```

A shape can be a shape connection at the same time. Once a few rectangles are added to the canvas, lines can be added to connect them. Since a line in your design is recognized as a `ShapeConnection` any operation involving the line will invoke the `Canvas` to let the `ConnectionManager` handle the graph. In this design it is important that `Line` is immutable.

Cascades are triggered by the removal of an annotated shape. You'll need to manage these cascades carefully: if an exception occurs somewhere along the way you are left with an incomplete graph.

This code only serves to give you an idea. Also I'm leaving the implementation of the connection manager to your imagination. Guava has been mentioned in one of the comments. A [BiMultiMap](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/guava-discuss/FUi4KUlaB-s) would have served your purpose just right, too bad they haven't released it yet. In any case, I would certainly have a look at letting the specifics of the `ConnectionManager` be handled by an existing library; many have been written that will fit your needs.

Note that there are no [circular dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_dependency) in this design.

Comment: Using these annotations is a very interesting approach. thanks!