# DDD : nested aggregates and many to many relationships

Tags: many-to-many, domain-driven-design, aggregate

I'm currently working on a Publishing Bounded Context. The main players in this context are **Product** and **Listing**.

Product : can be listed in multiple marketplaces. One **Product** Many **Listing**.

Listing : can have many products because some marketplace support variation listing. One **Listing** Many **Product**.

Based on the above I have a Many-To-Many relationship between **Listing** and **Product**.

I created an aggregate for both. The Product aggregate which contains listings and the Listing Aggregate which contains products.

Is it acceptable to have **Listing** defined in both aggregates or should I define Listing once to be used in both aggregates?

First **Listing** would be within the product aggregate because the product AR has a factory method that enforces rules when creating Listing(such as avoid duplicate listing in same marketplace and ensure we have stock qty for listing)

Second **Listing** would be an aggregate root which can contains info from many **Product** needed at the moment of publishing. This way I can create method on Listing to map it to a schema definition provided by different marketplaces (such as Ebay and Amazon). Also I want to be able to persist Listing independently from Listings within the same Product.

Do the two aggregates have too much overlap with duplicate definitions ? Is this to be expected within one  bounded context?

Also how can I keep the duplicate representation of Listing synchronize with each other?

Comment: Could you share more info about? 1. The first Listing's responsibility, is it just an object recording which marketplace the product are supposed to be published? 2.What does "This way I can create method on Listing to map it to a schema definition provided by different marketplaces" mean in the second Listing? Do you want to transform your product to Amazon's product schema?

Comment: Could you possibly model a "Variation Listing" distinct from a "Regular Listing" It sounds to me like they may be separate things? As for what is an aggregate or not, look for your transactional consistency boundaries. This may be a starting point to help you decide what is what.

Comment: The first listing definition within the product aggregate would be an object recording what marketplace it is published on (along with what price, title, qty). The second Listing definition would be its own AR which knows how to map itself to Amazon Product Schema and Ebay schema whatever the case may be.

Comment: the workflow goes something like this. Listing are created or modified in the Product AR (enforcing business rules). Then I will query for all listing with status Created or Modified. For each Listing returned I will invoke its mapping logic and call a synchronous web service(ebay) and asynchronous web service(amazon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First Listing would be within the product aggregate because the product AR has a factory method that enforces rules when creating Listing(such as avoid duplicate listing in same marketplace and ensure we have stock qty for listing)

Should a product know its own stock, its own marketplaces, its own listings and create listings too? This is too much responsibility for an entity! I would suggest to let a ListingFactory check the stock and the marketplces with other services or repositories that hold this information.

> Is it acceptable to have Listing defined in both aggregates or should I define Listing once to be used in both aggregates? Also how can I keep the duplicate representation of Listing synchronize with each other?

Avoid cyclic dependency between Product and Listing and a mess by maintaining a single list (have a look at this question for a similar tangle: [How to design many-to-many relationships on deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620599/how-to-design-many-to-many-relationships-on-deletion/15651811#15651811)). Seems to me you should have an aggregate of marketplaces, which contains your listings. You could setup a marketplace service or repository that gets all Listings if you need to access all listings based on a product (like in the ListingFactory I proposed).

> Do the two aggregates have too much overlap with duplicate definitions ?

Your definition of product "can be listed in multiple marketplaces" is not a very satisfying definition, because after reading this definition the question still remains: What is it then that can be listed? At its core a product can be defined without knowledge of listings, but within this context it probably would still be better to explicitly name the relationship. Since a (product) listing can not be defined without a product, but a product can be defined without a listing. They need not be duplicates. I would expect your product to be completely listing-unaware, but related to listings within the context.

> Is this to be expected within one bounded context?

All definitions build on each other, so within any context you can expect overlap, duplication, synonyms, extensions, near similarity, cross-referencing, different types of relationships, etc. It requires quite a bit of investigatory consciousness to separate the primary from the secondary, the predicates from the subjects and objects, the nucleus from the membrane. However, this is also what makes it so much fun :)

*definition of word*: "A single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence.."

*definition of sentence*: "A set of words that is complete in itself, typically containing a subject and predicate, conveying a statement, question, exclamation.."